# Swift Firebase Facebook didCompleteWithResult error

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, fbsdkloginkit

I am currently trying to enable Facebook login with Firebase in my swift project. I have followed multiple tutorials, and created a Facebook app, and filled in the necessary info (app ID, valid OAuth redirect URI etc).

However, when I try to sign in - I get an error in the didCompleteWithResult function. To be more specific, on this line:

```
let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: result.token.tokenString)
```

This is what the whole function looks like:

```
 func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

        print("Works!")

        if error != nil {
            print("Error")
        } else {
            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: result.token.tokenString)
            print("It worked.")
            print(credential)
        }

    }
```

So as you can see on the code, according to the function - there is no error (according to the if else (error) statement). What could be the problem here?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your credentials with this instead.

```
let facebookCredential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
```

Comment: When trying to log in, does your app even re-direct you to FB? What happens after you enter your log-in details?

Comment: Well, when I click on 'Sign in with Facebook' it takes me to the authorization. It says that I have already authorized it, then I click OK. After that, I get taken to just a blank page. So when I click 'done' in the upper left corner, I get this error.

Comment: Have you tried checking to see what `loginButtonWillLogin` delegate returns?

Comment: I have put the loginButtonWillLogin to return true, and I put a print ("hello") which all ran fine in the console.

Comment: Can you create a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) containing all of your VC code? Its hard to help based off of just that one method

Comment: I solved the problem! The problem was that I for some reason had 2 different functions in my appDelegate (openUrl/sourceApplication).